# how to add image on drop down button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

my output code is:-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>

#one
{
margin-left:150px;
}

</style>
<body>
<select id="one">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>

</body>
</html>
```

this code is jest output of drop down box 
but now I think add image on drop down list like below image[image]

I want to change the default appearance of the arrow of a dropdown list so that works out in all browsers.

Answer (score 2):

Try This Below Css....

```
select#one {
    -moz-appearance: none;
    background: url("../images/select_arrow.png");
    text-indent: 0.01px;
    text-overflow: "";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a css property (only works for modern browser):

```
.dropdown {
    background: url(path/to/image) top right no-repeat;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
}
```

For IE:

```
select::-ms-expand { display: none; }
```

Follow [this small tutorial](http://uplifted.net/programming/change-default-select-dropdown-style-just-css/).

Comment: Link only answer are not reliable for future uses. Your should give us a brief summary of the article, the link is an extra.